# how to display a website portion into my web site

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I am Trying to display the Sugar Rates on My Web page But I am Unable to do that.Actualy there is a web site on which sugar rates are displayed and i want to read the rates on my asp.net web page.Below is web site link

http://www.sugaronline.com/

and i wan to display the this portion on my web

[image]

Please any One Help me to do this in asp.net

Comment: did you try using iframe to display it?

Comment: Sir I frame is not authentic Solution and also there enable scrolls that i don't want

Comment: Well, unless they have some sort of API, you'll probably not be able to get the prices without parsing the page in some way.

Comment: You can parse the HTML of the second link in ASP.net or javascript. And then display specific fields.

Comment: Will U please Give example code to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try By this method.

```
<html>
 <head>
<title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

  <style type="text/css">
  #container{
width:100px;
height:400px;
border:1px solid #000; 
overflow:hidden;
margin:auto;
}
#container iframe {
width:200px;
height:750px;
margin-left:-100px;
margin-top:-350px;   
border:0 solid;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>


<div id="container">
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Refer this [Link](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?108520-Show-part-of-webpage-in-iframe)